# With transaction.atomic() and transaction.commit()

Tags: django, transactions, celery, django-celery, django-1.8

I've following block of code

```
def db_insert():

    success = True

    with transaction.atomic():
       try:

       '''
        Some data base inserts
       '''

       except:
          success = False


    if success:
        transaction.commit()
        celery_task.delay()

    return
```

I want to understand couple of things regarding transactions and celery task

- Will the transaction be committed twice?
- How can I test, whether the transaction is committed twice or not?
- Is there better way to make sure celery task will be able to read data that was written in transaction?

Note - Django version is 1.8. Also neither it is possible to upgrade to 1.9 or use other packages